# Do you know of a spinning plate for microwave?

Tags: microwave

I have a microwave oven that does not have a turntable. I have not had success finding something that will rotate my food to make food heat more evenly.

Does anyone have or know of such a product?

Comment: Keep in mind before buying any gadget to make a turntable inside your microwave - a brand new microwave can be had for around $40 USD... https://www.target.com/p/sunbeam-0-7-cu-ft-700-watt-microwave-oven-black-sgcmv807bk-07/-/A-12737266

Comment: Is your microwave too old or too new? Really old ones (25+ y) didn't have it and required turning the food periodically. Some new ones rotate the field instead and _don't_ require anything extra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

[image]

It's called a "micro-go-round", as you can see from the picture.  Simply search for "spring loaded microwave turntable."

Comment: Hi, we have a rule against link-only answers. I know that this information looks sufficient for now, but links go dead. It would be quite helpful to write out what this thing is called, and if it is only a brand-specific name, to also say what search terms you used to find it. Then others will be able to find alternatives if they wish.

Comment: “Spring loaded” worked when “wind up” had not. Thank you very much!

Comment: @rumtscho link is an affiliate link - is that allowed?

Comment: @SnakeDoc I understand an "affiliate link" to be an link that is intended to bring some benefit to the poster.  That is not my intention, as I just posted a link from Amazon.  However, since one can easily Google "Micro-Go-Round" and find several sellers, I have removed the link.

Comment: @moscafj It's possible SE converts them to affiliate links, that would be devious indeed.

Comment: @SnakeDoc It doesn't look like an affiliate link in the edit history on my phone, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @nick012000 it does seem to be devious after all - SE automatically changes all Amazon links into affiliate links and pockets the cash themselves: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-links